# Join & print only values with text and add comma between

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, join

I have a form with radiobuttons and a button to generate text based on values of these radiobuttons to texfield.

There are questions which consideres same problem (disease) and the questions are symptoms of this disease, like:

- Do you have symptom number 1 (radiobuttons YES with value="symptom 1" and NO with no value (value="")
- Do you have symptom number 2 (radiobuttons YES with value="symptom 2" and NO with value="")
  ...etc..

and the button then supposo to generate= Patient has symptoms of this disease: symptom 1, symptom 2, symptom 3.

**The question is**: How can i join the values of these radiobuttons and add comma and space (, ) between them. Also i dont want to include those values where no is selected (and no commas and blank space either). So the output would be if symptom 1 yes, symptom 2 no, symptom 3 yes, symptrom 4 no: Patiens has symptoms of this disease; symptom 1, symptom 3.

It would be even nicer if the word "and" could be also done.

If i set them in arrays it always pushes the comma whether no or yes is checked and therefore it needs some trimming (or something...?)

Now my jquery looks like:

JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY:

```
$("#BUTTON").click(function () {
var symptom1 = $("input[name=symptom1]:checked").val();
var symptom2 = $("input[name=symptom2]:checked").val();
var symptom3 = $("input[name=symptom3]:checked").val();
var symptom4= $("input[name=symptom4]:checked").val();

$("#RESULTTEXTBOX").val("Patient has symptoms of this disease" + symptom1 + symptom2 + symptom3 + symptom4 + ".");
```

HTML:

```
 Symptom1 ?<input id="symptom1yes" name="symptom1" type="radio" value=" symptom1" /> YES 
    <input id="symptom1no" name="symptom1" type="radio" value="" />NO<br>

Symptom2 ?<input id="symptom2yes" name="symptom2" type="radio" value=" symptom2" /> YES 
    <input id="symptom2no" name="symptom2" type="radio" value="" />NO<br>

Symptom3 ?<input id="symptom3yes" name="symptom3" type="radio" value=" symptom3" /> YES 
    <input id="symptom3no" name="symptom3" type="radio" value="" />NO<br>

Symptom4 ?<input id="symptom4yes" name="symptom4" type="radio" value=" symptom4" /> YES 
    <input id="symptom4no" name="symptom4" type="radio" value="" />NO<br><br>
    <button id="BUTTON">Generate text</button>
    <br><br>
    <textarea cols="34" id="RESULTTEXTBOX" name="RESULTTEXTBOX" rows="1" style="height: 98px; width: 473px"></textarea>
```

EDIT: DEMO

```js
    $("#BUTTON").click(function () {
    var symptom1 = $("input[name=symptom1]:checked").val();
    var symptom2 = $("input[name=symptom2]:checked").val();
    var symptom3 = $("input[name=symptom3]:checked").val();
    var symptom4= $("input[name=symptom4]:checked").val();

    $("#RESULTTEXTBOX").val("Patient has symptoms of this disease" + symptom1 + symptom2 + symptom3 + symptom4 + ".");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

     Symptom1 ?<input id="symptom1yes" name="symptom1" type="radio" value=" symptom1" /> YES 
        <input id="symptom1no" name="symptom1" type="radio" value="" />NO<br>
        
    Symptom2 ?<input id="symptom2yes" name="symptom2" type="radio" value=" symptom2" /> YES 
        <input id="symptom2no" name="symptom2" type="radio" value="" />NO<br>
        
    Symptom3 ?<input id="symptom3yes" name="symptom3" type="radio" value=" symptom3" /> YES 
        <input id="symptom3no" name="symptom3" type="radio" value="" />NO<br>
        
    Symptom4 ?<input id="symptom4yes" name="symptom4" type="radio" value=" symptom4" /> YES 
        <input id="symptom4no" name="symptom4" type="radio" value="" />NO<br><br>
        <button id="BUTTON">Generate text</button>
        <br><br>
        <textarea cols="34" id="RESULTTEXTBOX" name="RESULTTEXTBOX" rows="1" style="height: 98px; width: 473px"></textarea>
```

Comment: Radio buttons do not make the best UI device for a binary (Yes/No) answers. Everything will become much simpler for the user and for you if you use checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `^=`in the selector to get all the selected radios with name starting with "symptom", and, then, get put values using `$.map` into an array, which can be joined using commas:

```
var selectedSymptoms = $.map($("input[name^='symptom']:checked"),
                             function(radioButton) { return radioButton.value });
var selectedSymtomsYes = selectedSymptoms.filter(function(symptom) { return symptom });

var selectedSymptomsText = selectedSymtomsYes.join(",");
```

To have the text with "and", you can do this instead of the last line:

```
var selectedSymptomsText = selectedSymtomsYes.join(",").replace(/,(?!.*,)/gmi, "and");
```

Comment: I edited my question where i added working demo. In that demo your solution didnt work : when i replaced the symptom1,2,3 and 4 with this new variable it still keep showing the commas when i choose NO in symptom option.

Comment: @JohnDou Check my edited answer. Added a filter to exclude the empty values (from "no" radio buttons)

Comment: Worked like a charm, also the and part . Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.

Just add these lines to your code.

```
                var symtoms = (symptom1 == "" ? "" : symptom1 + ", ")
                        + (symptom2 == "" ? "" : symptom2 + ", ")
                        + (symptom3 == "" ? "" : symptom3 + ", ")
                        + (symptom4 == "" ? "" : symptom4 + ", ");
                var res = symtoms.trim().replace(/,{1,}$/, '');

                $("#RESULTTEXTBOX").val("Patient has symptoms of this disease" + res + ".");
```

Comment: Thanks but didnt work somehow. Got worked with
@Alberto Trindade Tavares solution though

Answer (score 0):

Here is something building Albertos answer, this however has support for oxford commas. Also, the filter expression is a little more readable imo.

```js
$("#BUTTON").click(function () {
  var symptoms = $("input[name^=symptom]:checked").filter(function(){return this.value.trim() !== ""; });
  var values = $.map(symptoms,function(e,i){ return e.value});

  $("#RESULTTEXTBOX").text("Patient has symptoms of this disease. " + formatArray(values) );
});

function formatArray(arr){
    var outStr = "";
    if (arr.length === 1) {
        outStr = arr[0];
    } else if (arr.length === 2) {
        outStr = arr.join(' and ');
    } else if (arr.length > 2) {
       outStr = arr.slice(0, -1).join(', ') + ', and ' + arr.slice(-1);
    }
    return outStr;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
   Symptom1 ?<input id="symptom1yes" name="symptom1" type="radio" value="symptom1" /> YES 
   <input id="symptom1no" name="symptom1" type="radio" value="" />NO<br>
   Symptom2 ?<input id="symptom2yes" name="symptom2" type="radio" value="symptom2" /> YES 
   <input id="symptom2no" name="symptom2" type="radio" value="" />NO<br>
   Symptom3 ?<input id="symptom3yes" name="symptom3" type="radio" value="symptom3" /> YES 
   <input id="symptom3no" name="symptom3" type="radio" value="" />NO<br>
   Symptom4 ?<input id="symptom4yes" name="symptom4" type="radio" value="symptom4" /> YES 
   <input id="symptom4no" name="symptom4" type="radio" value="" />NO<br><br>
   <button id="BUTTON">Generate text</button>
   <br><br>
   <textarea cols="34" id="RESULTTEXTBOX" name="RESULTTEXTBOX" rows="1" style="height: 98px; width: 473px"></textarea>
</body>
```